# How many Dragon Balls Dragons are there in Dragon Ball now?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

So far there is a Dragon on Earth, there was a Dragon of the nameks though not sure if he's still alive, there was an universal size Dragon, and another one introduced in the Dragon Ball Super manga. Are they all? Are all of them still alive?

How many Dragon Balls Dragons are there in Dragon Ball now?

Answer (score 0):

The seven Shadow Dragons include Naturon Shenron, Eis Shenron, Syn Shenron, Rage Shenron, Nuova Shenron, Haze Shenron, and Oceanus Shenron. They only possess one Dragon Ball, though. And if you include Porunga, Shenron, Super Shenron, Ultimate Shenron, and Black Smoke Shenron, there are a total of 12 Dragons and 42 balls throughout the *Dragon Ball* series.

Comment: Your count of the Dragon Balls is wrong. There are 7 for Shenron, 7 for Porunga, 2 for Toronbo and 7 for Super Senron, for a total of 23 in DB+DBS. If you add GT, you have 7 more for Ultimate Shenron. Normal Shenron shares the same set of Dragon Balls with its evil versions, just like Dende's Shenron shares them with Kami's Shenron and both incarnations of Porunga share one set.

Comment: @Gae.S., sorry for the incorrect feedback.

Comment: Are you going to do anything about it?